# SQLite Database Schema: Empty Tables

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm fairly new to SQL/SQLite and am making a database for storing highscores/power/misc other objects. This is how it's set up (it's a little more complicated but this pertains to the question).

TABLE Worlds (0-4)
-world_id:Int

TABLE Levels (0-8)
-level_id:Int

TABLE GameRecord
-record_id:Int
-world_id:FK
-level_id:FK
-highscore:Int
-locked:Bool

My first two tables (Worlds and Levels) only have one key in their table (id). Is this the proper way to setup a database schema? It's in Android and SQLite, but I don't think that affects anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The only 'right' way to make a schema is the way that works for you. There's proper ways, recommended ways, etc... And it all boils down to exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fine way to set up a database schema *if* you plan to expand the `Worlds` and `Levels` tables to include more fields later. Things like a name, or other metadata, would be good to put there.

If your worlds and levels are merely numbers and nothing else, you can just use integers in your `GameRecord` `world_id` and `level_id` fields without worrying about the foreign key relationship. You could also just start this way (without the other tables) and then change those columns to be (or be treated like) foreign keys to the other tables in the future, when you have actual data to put there.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if it's frowned upon or improper to use a nearly empty table.